# Multi Unit convertor android application

Tags: java, android

I am designing a multi unit convertor app...

for that i created a spinner and store its value in array.
then an edittext where we can put numbers

i want when I press convert button it takes unit from the spinner like weight,currency etc whatever the user select then and solve the equation like if i select weight category
and put any value in edittext it shuold multiply this value by 2.205 and display result in a extview.

code is here

public class spinnerdropdown extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    TextView textView1;
    CardView crdvspinner;
    Spinner unitspinner;

    EditText edtinputspinner;
    Button convertbtnspinner;
    TextView txtvresultspinner;

    String[] unitarray= {"Currency","Weight","Liquid","Temperature","Area","Length"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinnerdropdown);

        textView1= findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        crdvspinner= findViewById(R.id.crdvspinner);
        unitspinner= findViewById(R.id.unitspinner);

      edtinputspinner= findViewById(R.id.edtinputspinner);
        convertbtnspinner= findViewById(R.id.convertbtnspinner);
      txtvresultspinner= findViewById(R.id.txtvresultspinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(spinnerdropdown.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,unitarray);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        unitspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        unitspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String value= adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
              Toast.makeText(spinnerdropdown.this,value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        convertbtnspinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String firstvalue= edtinputspinner.getText().toString();

            if (spinnerdropdown.this=="Weight"){

                double kg= Double.parseDouble(firstvalue);
                double pound= kg * 2.205;
                txtvresultspinner.setText(""+pound);
            }
    }
});
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You've stated what you want to do and shown some code you tried. Is something not working? Is your question "how do I get the current selection from a spinner?" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your selected item in spinner by making the `value` global by:

```
public class spinnerdropdown extends AppCompatActivity {
    //everything same 
    //just add
     String value= "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinnerdropdown);

       //....as it is

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(spinnerdropdown.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,unitarray);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        unitspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        unitspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                value= adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();//change here remove String
              Toast.makeText(spinnerdropdown.this,value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        convertbtnspinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //also you can check if user has not selected anything as
            if(value.eqals("")){
              Toast.makeText(spinnerdropdown.this,"Please select some data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return;
            }
              //use the value just added at top
            if (value.equals("Weight")){

                double kg= Double.parseDouble(firstvalue);
                double pound= kg * 2.205;
                txtvresultspinner.setText(""+pound);
            }
    }
});
    }
}
```